# How can I change data object in Vue component depending on route and using vue-route?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I faced issue while working on vuejs application:

I have to change titles in few vuejs components, depending on routes

`routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: { //with default data
        FirstScreen, 
        Advantages,
        Slider,
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/moscow', 
      components: { //with special data for Moscow
        FirstScreen,
        Advantages,
        Slider,
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/berlin', 
      components: { //with special data for Berlin
        FirstScreen,
        Advantages,
        Slider,
      },
    },
  ],`

and data at all .vue files looks like this

```
data() {
  return {
    defaultTitle: 'some string',
    defaultArray: ['defaultFirst', 'defaultSec'],
  };
},
```

And I have about 100 cities... how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use vue-router you can 'hook into' one of it's extremely helpful methods called beforeEach. This methods acts as a sort of middleware and runs before any given route is executed.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    document.title = to.meta.title
    next();
});
```

Comment: Kevin, thx u for your answer, it's helpful. But in my case not only titles changes. In fact I have to pass strings array or more that one array in each component depending on routes for titles and subtitles(h1/h2/h3). May be you can help me with this too?

Comment: Hi, I would strongly recommend against using your router to pass data as it sort of defeats the purpose a MVC model such as Vue. Ideally you'll want to fetch data from within your Vue components based off of the given route (e.g. /posts/123 fetches data for post 123 from your server). By separating your router and component logic you maintain your application's modularity.

This exact same issue is discussed here [https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/398](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/398)

Comment: To elaborate, imagine having a City component which gets rendered everytime a user visits a route that should display a city's information (e.g. /berlin or /amsterdam), regardless of what city was passed in the url. This City component then fetches data from your back-end for that given city by checking for the current route parameters in its constructor and populates the component with said data.

Answer (score 0):

If someone will need to implement data transfer depending on routes and really want to hardcode it to route file it is possible with this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/docs/en/essentials/passing-props.md

In my case it will be looks like:

```
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  components: {
    FirstScreen,
    Advantages,
    BigSlider,
  },
  props: {
    FirstScreen: {
      title: 'title',
      subtitle: ['arr1', 'arr2'],
    },
    Advantages: {
      title: 'title',
      advantages: 'advantages',
    },
    BigSlider: {
      title: 'title',
      slideText: 'slideText',
    },
  },
},
```

and in component you have to do something like this

```
export default {
props: {
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  subtitle: {
    type: Array,
  },
},
```

It will work fine, but I agree with Kevin Karsopawiro in part that this approach is unmaintainable. So using city-component for fetching data from back-end is best in my case.